# Find the row in Sheet1 with the same number of row in Sheet2 and add text to cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have data in `Sheet2` and then I want to copy it to `Sheet1`. So, I have to find the row in `Sheet1` that have the same number of row in `Sheet2`:

`Sheet1` and `Sheet2` look like this:

[image: sheet2]

[image: sheet1]

How can I find the row in `Sheet1` that has the same "num" column A in `Sheet2`  and add to cell C in `Sheet1`  the value of cell C in `Sheet2` ?

Here is an example for row 2 "num 6" - it has to look like : 
[image: Action number 6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - the general idea is you can use the `Find` method of a `Range` to find rows on both sheets with matching `num`s:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    'set sheet1 traking value for i = to lookup on sheet2
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'loop through indexes
    For i = 1 To 6
        Set rng = ws.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=i)
        rng.Offset(0, 3).Value = rng.Offset(0, 3) & AddToTraking(i)
    Next i

End Sub

Function AddToTraking(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = ws.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=num)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        str = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
    Else
        str = ""
    End If

    AddToTraking = str

End Function
```

Comment: wath i want is to do that to all rows : number  6 and 4 and 5 , it well be daynamic

Comment: So change the value of `i` - or write a `For..Next` loop to cycle through the values you want. People aren't here to write you entire application ! ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I asked for that because I do not know how to write it , I am still new on vBA

Comment: i get this Error "The indication does not belong to the selection"

Comment: Are you worksheets not called `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` ?

Comment: thank you it's working yes i change the names of sheets

Comment: so now i well write a loop to do it for all rows